# Samba: Sharing some folders without duplicate?

Tags: linux, samba

I keep all my `Photos` on my Share: `//COMPUTERNAME/Photos`

In the `Photos` share, it contains all the years folders follow by album name, example:

```
//COMPUTERNAME/Photos/2012/New York/
//COMPUTERNAME/Photos/2011/France/
//COMPUTERNAME/Photos/2011/Party Night/
```

Only I have access to `Photos` share with username and password, it is not accessible by anyone.

However, I want to share a few photos albums for my family but I don't want them to have access to the `Photos` share.

I can create a share called `//COMPUTERNAME/PhotosShare/` but I don't want to copy a few photos albums from `Photos` share.

In the `//COMPUTERNAME/PhotosShare/` share I want something like this:

`//COMPUTERNAME/PhotosShare/2012 New York` link with `//COMPUTERNAME/Photos/2012/New York/`

Is it possible to use `ln` command? I don't think that going to work due to user permission access on Samba.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could accomplish what you want by setting up samba as follows. First you're going to want to use Samba's user security mode (`security = user`) in your `smb.conf` file.

Next you'll want to setup a user called `smbshare` in your `smbpasswd` file. This user will only exist within Samba, so make sure it doesn't exist within the Linux side (i.e. `/etc/passwd`).

Next map this Samba user in the `smbusers` file so that it maps to your Linux account.

```
# unix acct. = samba acct.
myuser = smbshareuser
```

This will give this Samba user access as you to the file system.

Finally you'll want to setup a directory with the links to the different photo shares and add this directory as a share within Samba's `smb.conf` file.

```
[PhotosShare]
  comment = My Shared Photos
  path = /path/to/dir/with/links
  browseable = yes
  read only = yes
  valid users = smbshareuser
```

#### example links directory

```
$ ll /path/to/dir/with/links
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 49 Jun  8 04:01 album1 -> /path/to/album/album1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 58 Jun  8 04:00 album2 -> /path/to/album/album2
```

After making these above changes make sure to restart the samba services (smbd & nmbd).

Comment: Thanks @slm - you have explained how to share a single directory from a photo share. I was talking about linking a few folders in a `PhotosShare` from a `photos` share

Comment: No the directory `/path/to/dir/with/links` would be a directory with links to the various folders that you want to share with others.